# Is this a bug? expression(mu) appears as a proportional-to symbol instead of as mu in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, symbols

This is my minimal code example that knits on my computer (Windows 10, R 4.3.1, latest version of knitr and tinytex) but shows a proportional symbol where the mu should be.

````
---
title: "temp"
output: pdf_document
date: "2024-02-26"
---


## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r}
plot(1:2,1:2)
mtext(expression(mu), at=1.5, line=-2)
```
````

And this is a screenshot of the output:[image: PDF with plot and symbol]

Is this a bug in Rmarkdown? If not, what can I do to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Consider restarting your R kernel/ Rstudio. Cannot replicate the problem

Comment: I’m guessing that it is due to using a non-standard font where the glyph encoded is different than the expected lowercase Greek letter.

Comment: Have you tried using a different PDF viewer to look at the output?  It could be the viewer that is displaying the mu improperly.  Like @Onyambu, I see a mu when I run your code.